# Как установить StyleSheet для индикатора сортировки в QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qtableview, qheaderview

Есть таблица `QTableView` с сортировкой.

Не получается установить `StyleSheet` для индикатора сортировки.

Надо изменить цвет, размер и положение индикатора.

Пробовал так:

```
QHeaderView::down-arrow {
    color:#ff0;
    width: 26px;
    height:18px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom right;
}
```

Но изменяется только позиция индикатора

[image: мой вариант]
[image: как должно получитьс]

2 изображение это как примерно должно получиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.view = QTableView(self)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableWidget.SelectRows)
        self.view.sortByColumn(0, Qt.DescendingOrder)
        self.view.setModel(QStandardItemModel(4, 4))
        for each in [
            (row, col, 
            QStandardItem(f'item {row}_{col}')) \
                for row in range(4) for col in range(4)]:
            self.view.model().setItem(*each)
            
        self.view.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)


Stylesheet = '''
QHeaderView::up-arrow {
    image: url(img/up.png);                           /* <----  */
}
QHeaderView::down-arrow {
    width: 26px;
    height:18px;
    subcontrol-position: center right;     
    image: url(img/down.png);                            /* <---- */
}
QHeaderView::section { 
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #3884c3;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
QHeaderView::section:vertical {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet) 
    w = Dialog()
    w.resize(500, 250)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**up.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**down.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, а куда можно поместить эти изображения? Просто в папку или куда ни будь в код?

Comment: @KeyisB пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  Поместить изображения можно куда угодно, в моем примере они лежат в папке `img`, можно и в код, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: пикчи складывайте в файл ресурсов, и грузите от туда же... типа image: url(:/icons/down.png);